# Do subtraction for the first subset category

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Here my data

```
structure(list(code = c(11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L), date = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2017-08-20 00:00:00.000", 
"2017-08-21 00:00:00.000", "2017-08-22 00:00:00.000", "2017-08-24 00:00:00.000", 
"2017-08-25 00:00:00.000", "2017-08-27 00:00:00.000", "2017-08-28 00:00:00.000"
), class = "factor"), x1 = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 15L, 20L, 15L, 10L), 
    action = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x2 = c(4L, 3L, 0L, 
    12L, 17L, 12L, 7L)), .Names = c("code", "date", "x1", "action", 
"x2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I need for first category of action column,
subtract x1-x2 and the result in "base column".
Values for zero category of action are  just copied in base from x2,
there are no calculations with them.

So desired output

```
code    date                    x1   action x2  base
11202   2017-08-20 00:00:00.000 4   0        4  4
11202   2017-08-21 00:00:00.000 3   0        3  3
11202   2017-08-22 00:00:00.000 2   1        0  2
11202   2017-08-24 00:00:00.000 15  1        12 3
11202   2017-08-25 00:00:00.000 20  1        17 3
11202   2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 15  1        12 3
11202   2017-08-28 00:00:00.000 10  1         7 3
```

How to do it?

Comment: Something like `df$what=ifelse(df$action==1,df$x1-df$x2,df$base)`?

Comment: @user2974951, yes, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward to do.

```
df <- df 
    %>% mutate(base = ifelse(action > 0,x1-x2,x2))
```

You check if the action is above 0, and if it is, subtract x2 from x1, otherwise you pass x2 through unchanged.